# How can I export my bookmarks and import them into a table?

Tags: html, json, csv, datatables, bookmarks

I have hundreds of bookmarks that I have collected over the years that I would like to put into a searchable table with extra information such as categories, types, descriptions etc.

My first attempt at this was manually putting them into a JSON file and then using the DataTables plug-in to display them, however, this was tedious and time-consuming.

The second attempt was to use Wordpress and use Advanced Custom Fields to do this but again still quite tedious.

Obviously, I can export my bookmarks as an HTML file and I'm considering editing and styling this file to suit my needs but it is absolutely massive and also has loads of extraneous information. I've been trying to use CSV conversions of this file to import it into various Wordpress plug-ins that say they offer this exact functionality to know avail. I've also tried doing something similar with firefox's backup that exports to a JSON file but again no luck.

I know that I will have to manually put in some of the information, but I'm trying to cut down on the workload by about a third. Am I going about this the wrong way? Is it even possible? Just wondering if anyone out there has tried to do the same thing and how they went about it.

Comment: which browser for which you are telling to export bookmark?

Comment: Chrome, but all of them export to html as afar as i can tell, firefox also backs up in JSON. I've been looking for plugins that do what I want - no luck so far.

Comment: Yes agree. one way you can achieve this is bye parsing exported html file and then extract all the hyperlink and bookmark text from it.

Comment: I wrote something a little while ago which used Papa Parse to parse a CSV file and populate a DataTable with the results. If you think that this would help let me know and I'll document the process for you.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

That was a lovely challenge, thanks. Basically, what I've done is saved the exported bookmarks as HTML and then created a simple page with an empty table. Then my JS does this:

```
$(function() {
    var example = $("#example").DataTable({
        "responsive": true,
        "columns": [
            {
                "title": "Title",
                "data": "text"
            },{
                "title": "Date added",
                "data": "date",
                "render": function(d){
                    return moment(d, "X").format("DD/MM/YYYY");
                }
            },{
                "title": "URI",
                "data": "href",
                "render": function(d){
                    return $("<a></a>",{
                        "text": d,
                        "href": d
                    }).prop("outerHTML");
                }
            }
        ],
        "initComplete": function(settings, json) {
            $.get("bookmarks_12_2_16.html", function( data ) {
                $(data).find("dl").children("dt").children("a").each(function(k, v){
                    if(!~~$(v).attr("href").indexOf("http")){
                        example.row.add({
                            "href": $(v).attr("href"),
                            "text": $(v).text(),
                            "date": $(v).attr("add_date")
                        });
                    }
                });
                example.draw();
            });
        }
    });
});
```

Basically it `get`s the HTML and iterates over the `dt`s within the `dl` and, if the `href` is `http` or `https`, it adds it to the table with the correct date (you'd date function might have to be different seeing as I'm in the UK and I'm using [momentjs](http://momentjs.com/)). Hope that helps.

Comment: You are a life saver! I'll be trying out this later today, but just reading through it I can see how it'll work. Luckily i'm in the UK too so shouldn't have to change much/anything. Thanks so much!

Comment: Just a note for future users of this sample code, you'll need https://datatables.net/ and jQuery and as noted momentjs (or you could remove the date code).

Answer (score 1):

You can parse exported file from chrome using below:

Here i have used SAX parser to parse and extract url and link from bookmark.

Below three classes will parse xml and print bookmark url title and link.

you can export it into csv or you can use it in better way to generate table dynamically from which you can search.

```
import javax.xml.parsers.SAXParser;
import javax.xml.parsers.SAXParserFactory;
import org.xml.sax.SAXException;
import org.xml.sax.XMLReader;

public class BookmarkReader {

    public static void main(String argv[]) {

        try {
            SAXParserFactory factory = SAXParserFactory.newInstance();
            SAXParser saxParser = factory.newSAXParser();

            XMLReader xmlReader = saxParser.getXMLReader();

            try {
                xmlReader.setFeature(
                        "http://apache.org/xml/features/continue-after-fatal-error",
                        true);
            } catch (SAXException e) {
                System.out.println("error in setting up parser feature");
            }

            xmlReader.setContentHandler(new ContentHandler());
            xmlReader.setErrorHandler(new MyErrorHandler());
            xmlReader.parse("C:\\Users\\chetankumar.p\\Documents\\bookmarks_12_2_16.html");

        } catch (Throwable e) {
            System.out.println(e.getMessage());
        }

    }
}


import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;
import org.xml.sax.Attributes;
import org.xml.sax.SAXException;
import org.xml.sax.helpers.DefaultHandler;

public class ContentHandler extends DefaultHandler {

    class Bookmark {

        public String title;
        public String href;
    }

    Bookmark bookmark;
    List<Bookmark> bookmarks = new ArrayList<>();

    @Override
    public void endDocument() throws SAXException {
        for (Bookmark bookmark1 : bookmarks) {
            System.out.println("title : " + bookmark1.title);
            System.out.println("title : " + bookmark1.href);
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void startElement(String uri, String localName,
            String qName, Attributes attributes)
            throws SAXException {

        if (qName.equalsIgnoreCase("a")) {
            bookmark = new Bookmark();
            System.out.println("href ::: " + attributes.getValue("HREF"));
            bookmark.href = attributes.getValue("HREF");
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void endElement(String uri, String localName, String qName) throws SAXException {
        if (qName.equalsIgnoreCase("a")) {

            bookmarks.add(bookmark);
            bookmark = null;
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void characters(char[] ch, int start, int length) throws SAXException {
        if (bookmark != null) {
            bookmark.title = new String(ch, start, length);
        }
    }

}


import org.xml.sax.ErrorHandler;
import org.xml.sax.SAXException;
import org.xml.sax.SAXParseException;

public class MyErrorHandler implements ErrorHandler {

    private String getParseExceptionInfo(SAXParseException spe) {
        String systemId = spe.getSystemId();

        if (systemId == null) {
            systemId = "null";
        }

        String info = "URI=" + systemId + " Line="
                + spe.getLineNumber() + ": " + spe.getMessage();

        return info;
    }

    public void warning(SAXParseException spe) throws SAXException {
        System.out.println("Warning: " + getParseExceptionInfo(spe));
    }

    public void error(SAXParseException spe) throws SAXException {
        String message = "Error: " + getParseExceptionInfo(spe);
        System.out.println(message);
    }

    public void fatalError(SAXParseException spe) throws SAXException {
        String message = "Fatal Error: " + getParseExceptionInfo(spe);
        System.out.println(message);
    }
}
```

Comment: This looks great, unfortunately I don't know Java at all! I should have specified perhaps. However I can read some of whats going on in there and I can see how that would work - I think. Can I ask, does this create a CSV file then? And when you say export from chrome using this, do you run this as another program? Sorry I'm a total noob when it comes to Java. I'm still giving you a tick as I imagine this is correct from a Java perspective. Thank you!

Comment: Chrome will export file as html and if you will open file then it will be in xml format. then that file will become input in this program. this program will only print on java console and if you want it to export as csv then i will again updated this.

Comment: Because I understand JS and will be using DataTables I will go with annoyingmouse's solution, however you're answer may be of use to someone else who comes at this problem with Java so if you think that would help them then that would be great!

Answer (score 1):

Firefox Bookmarks to .xlsm [SOLVED]

---

I figured out how to get my bookmarks out of Firefox and into Excel. A macro processes them, and other macros get you around the Worksheet.

It uses: 1.) Firefox, 2.) SQLite3, 3.) DOS, 4.) Excel VBA, 5.) NirCmd (optional)

All you have to do is to categorize your bookmarks, and then click the sort button.

These two PDFs provide code for the BAT files, and explain how to set up the paths for the macros. More instructions are in the VBA of the xlsm. These three files are on my Google Docs.

I thought I'd share this, because it's cool, might be useful to others . . . and maybe someone can improve on what I have, or give me some more ideas . . . maybe this post can be left open.

---

bookmarks-to-CSV.pdf . . . This first page provides all you need to know, to get your Bookmarks into a .CSV file (This won't do anything to your actual Bookmarks, it just extracts a copy of them.) . . . Then, the next few pages provide the details of what's going on . . . https://drive.google.com/open?id=1xYWPQtijqCzk-1nzTsTb0ZUVKYJNFokR

Custom UI Editor.pdf . . . Supporting info, and BAT file code to be set up . . . https://drive.google.com/open?id=1G2AWBamOrbAo2ZNDtUyYdzegjKzz34DA

bookmarks-p.xlsm . . . The Preview on Google Docs isn't that great.  Some supporting info is in the first four Worksheets.  Bookmarks are in the fifth Worksheet (see tabs across the bottom) . . . https://drive.google.com/open?id=1ZOuOBkdJjMx1T4xMUNG7sf6MDWurUqqy

Answer (score 0):

Use extensions on the Chrome Store to generate a JSON/CSV output. Converting that to table form should be fairly straightforward.

- [Bookmarks to JSON/CSV](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/export-historybookmarks-t/dcoegfodcnjofhjfbhegcgjgapeichlf) (including chrome history)
- [Bookmarks to
  JSON](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/bookmarks-to-json/ladccghgadelmlkjfkdjhjlinhogaibi/related) (root or folder based)
- [Bookmarks Table](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/bookmarks-table/eaabmhkokgaboihbikohlooneokghmcp) (view only, by date)